# How can I see if it is a circle or a path in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

I have a circle-like path in Sketch. How can I now see if it's really a circle (i.e it was created with the Oval tool) or if it's just a path with the shape of a circle.
They look the same and all the settings are the same, but when I export them to an SVG file the circle will be translated to a circle-tag and the path will be translated to a path-tag, which is a great difference.

Is there a way to differentiate them at all?

Comment: just a tip.....while you make a circle with oval tool....press shift and make.....it will come perfect circle... hope it helps :)

Comment: I knew that already, but thanks anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily via a plugin that checks what `selectedLayer.layers().objectAtIndex(0).className()` looks like.

Just copy and paste the following into the **Plugins › Custom Plugin** window, hit **Save…** and give it a nice name like **Is this a circle?** :)

```
try {
  var c = selection[0].layers().objectAtIndex(0).className()
  if(c == "MSOvalShape") {
    [doc showMessage:"Selected layer is a circle"]
  } else {
    [doc showMessage:"Selected layer is NOT a circle"]
  }
} catch(e) {
  [doc showMessage:"Selected layer is NOT a circle"]
}
```

Hope it helps!